# Manual sharing is read only on contact's record (single record) but a user still have delete button and it is working

Tags: administration

I want to make a contact visible to every user of our Org and it should be in read only mode. OWD is private for both Account and Contact.  I tried using manual sharing by giving read only access to all the user who required this contact. But when I check by login to individual user the delete button is also accessible and it is in delete mode.
Kindly help me to make a single contact record accessible to all user in a read-only mode.

Comment: Is your User you tried to login with, a System Admin profile?

Comment: No, he is having a Salesforce.com license user. I want to give read-only access to Salesforce.com license user & Force.com license user.

Comment: Did the user you logged in with happen to be the supervisor of the user who owned the contact? With standard objects, if roles are enabled, role hierarchies still apply when security is set to private. So a supervisor would be able to edit or delete a subordinate's records with a private sharing model. That feature can only be disabled on custom objects.

Comment: Role hierarchy is not enabled. But how it can happen when I am giving Read-only in manual sharing the Delete permission are still active.